# Save grouped Tabs in Microsoft edge

Tags: browser, tabs, microsoft-edge, browser-extension, group

How can I save multiple grouped tabs to set them as default when the browser starts? Just like the attached pic whenever I start the edge browsers they appear as grouped tabs.

[image: Grouped tabs in microsft edge]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this requirement can be fulfilled for the time being. I found this flag in Chrome: `#tab-groups-save`, the final effect is similar to bookmarks, But even with it enabled, the saved groups will disappear next time when you open chrome. I can't find it in Edge or Edge Canary, it seems that the relevant team has not developed the corresponding function.

So I recommend that you send feedback to relevant team, please press `Shift+Alt+I` to edit your suggestions and send it. This will help improve Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on **Microsoft Edge** regarding **saving tabs along with their groupings**. Currently, there are two solutions:

1- Utilize the **Workspace feature** introduced in version 114. (Note that this requires connecting the browser to a Microsoft account to function.)

[microsoft-edge-workspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-workspaces)

2- Use the following **extension**, compatible with both **Chrome** and **Edge**, which can save your tabs along with their groupings for you:

[Tabox - Save and Share Tabs](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tabox-save-and-share-tab/bdbliblipiempfdkkkjohnecmeknnpoa)